# Vertex ID updation in Titan DB

Tags: java, json, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

If we import an external vertex json file (which already contains an Vertex id) in our Titan graph how it's vertex id of that vertex is managed in Titan Graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titan generates its own identifiers. You can't supply your own. As such, when you import your vertex json file, the identifier supplied with it is not preserved and a new identifier is created. If you are importing multiple vertices and edges, you will need to keep track of the newly created vertices and their mapping to these new identifiers so that you can properly build edges between them.